# Why is the model of hyperelliptic curve proper?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

In wiki, the smooth projective model of an affine model is hyperelliptic curve is defined as follows:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperelliptic_curve

To be more precise, the equation defines a quadratic extension of $\mathbb C(x)$ (just the function field of the complex projective line), and it is that function field that is meant. The singular point at infinity can be removed (since this is a curve) by the normalization (integral closure) process. It turns out that after doing this, there is an open cover of the curve by two affine charts: the one already given by

$y^{2}=f(x)$

and another one given by

$w^{2}=v^{{2g+2}}f(1/v)$.

The glueing maps between the two charts are given by

$(x,y)\mapsto (1/x,y/x^{{g+1}})$

and

$(v,w)\mapsto (1/v,w/v^{{g+1}})$

I can see it is smooth by checking at charts, but how to show it is projective i.e proper curve?

Comment: Adding the URL is *not* enough. Using pictures inhabits others from finding your question through search engines like [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/).  The visually impaired *can't* read your question.  Please be nice to them and don't deprive them of the right to read your question.

Comment: [Voting on meta indicates agreement/disagreement.](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/30104/290189).  In the linked [meta] posts about text images, the higher the post score, the more the members agree with the its content.  This is *not* a suggestion, but a general consent of the community.  Most of [your images](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A395911+url%3A%22*.png%22) are text images.  Please note that [image is not a shortcut for not typing the question.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155601/259305).

Comment: Whether this is a general consent or not depends on votes on related posts.  Please note the diamond ♦ indicates that it's from a moderator, either per SE or network-wise.  If you *don't* agree, you have the right to downvote, just like what I and another user have done.

Comment: I have no problem with the downvote, that is how things work.

Comment: Your question's context depend heavily on Wiki's definition, and you've linked to this [off-site context with a hyperlink](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1807/290189).  This is strongly *discouraged* on SE.  The question body alone should contain sufficient context to be answered without the external content.

Comment: I disagree with you, that's what the problem is. I explained what I can check (using Jacobian criterion to see it's smooth), but don't know why it's proper.

Comment: My bad.  Excuse me for overlooking the paragraph that follows.  I remark that the "C(x)" is an object in the mathematical discourse, so it should be wrapped with `$` so that it would be [parsed and presented as mathematical markup (MathML)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22026/290189).  Apart from that, please terminate each sentence which ends with a formula with a full stop '.', like this: $$\sin^2 x - \cos^2 x = -\cos(2x).$$

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 OK, I will edit it, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map to P^1 given by taking the x coordinate is finite (check on affine charts). Finite morphisms are proper and therefore the hyperelliptic curve is proper.